# Uncaught ReferenceError: $hxClasses is not defined in Haxe js project

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, haxe

I am having an issue that I discussed on the Haxe IRC channel but was unable to come up with a fix. It seems to be a bug with the compiler.

Here is the Haxe code:

```
package;

import js.Lib;
import js.three.Three;
import haxe.Timer;

class Main {    

    public var timer:Timer;
    public var renderer:WebGLRenderer;
    public var scene:Scene;
    public var camera:PerspectiveCamera;

    public function new() {

        timer = new Timer(30);

        var w = Lib.window.innerWidth;
        var h = Lib.window.innerHeight;

        scene = new Scene();

        // create a red cube
        var material = new MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xff0000});
        var geometry = new CubeGeometry(50, 50, 50, 1, 1, 1, material, null);
        var cube = new Mesh(geometry, new MeshFaceMaterial());
        cube.position.set(0, 100, 0);
        scene.add(cube);
        // add some light
        var pointLight = new PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 0);
        pointLight.position.set(10, 50, 130);
        scene.add(pointLight);
        // and a camera
        camera = new PerspectiveCamera(70, w/h, 1, 1000);
        camera.position.z = 500;
        scene.add(camera);
        // setup renderer in the document
        renderer = new WebGLRenderer(null);
        renderer.setSize(w, h);

        Lib.document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        untyped Lib.window.onload = onLoad;
    }

    public function onLoad() {

        timer.run = function(){

            renderer.render(scene, camera, null, null);
        }
    }


    public static function main() {
        new Main();
    }


}
```

The solution is to get the compiler to add the following to the beginning of the JS file that it creates.

```
var $_, $hxClasses = $hxClasses || {},
```

As it stands right now the first line in the JS file looks like this

```
$estr = function() { return js.Boot.__string_rec(this,''); }
```

Not sure what needs to be done to fix this or a possible work around other than adding in that line by hand after compilation ?

Comment: The problem is with the haxe.Timer class. Minimal non-functioning example - http://pastebin.com/AxXF0CwC

Comment: Sorry, I'm still at work. What I was trying to say, is that it's nothing with your code, if you import the Timer and compile with the three.js library. It's there.

Comment: It also works the other way around. Remove the timer, and you'll get it rendered (just once ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue - three.js has Date.hx and Timer.hx files in it (older versions) delete them and it works (on my win install it's in c:\Motion-Twin\haxe\lib\three,js\0,2,46\ and c:\Motion-Twin\haxe\lib\three,js\0,2,46\haxe)

Comment: Just to add some more info - this will cause some issues as those modified files are there for a purpose (see https://github.com/labe-me/haxe-three.js )